# "Unable to find thread for evaluation." while running an external program in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, visual-studio-code, operating-system

I want to remote control 'my_program' using os.

```py
import os

os.system(my_program)
```

While in debug mode in VS-Code i can start the 'my_program', but as soon as it opens, i've no available thread in VS-Code to work with. Or atleast that's what i'm interpreting by the message 'Unable to find thread for evaluation.'. I can not execute any commands in the debug console anymore, for instance `3+3`, which should output 6.

As soon as i manually kill 'my_program' by simply closing it in the GUI, i can continue debugging.

***In Short***:

What i want: Open, use and Close 'my_program' with VSCode using os.system

What i get: Program opens, but VS debugging is somewhat offline, since it is 'Unable to find thread for evaluation.' and i can not continue debugging/closing the program via os.system

```py
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM my_program.exe")
```

EDIT: i can reproduce the same behaviour (freezed debugging console) using

```py
subprocess.call(my_program)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with

```py
subprocess.Popen(my_program)
```

`subprocess.call` and `os.system` block the terminal as long as the process being called is finished, thus 'freezing' the thread and debug window. `subprocess.popen` on the other hand is an asynchronous call which let's you interact with the terminal while the called process keeps running in the background

Comment: Did you try  "subProcess":  true in your launch.json ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message. The introspection just works when the debugger is stopped at a breakpoint. I've put a breakpoint in the code, stopped in it and everything works fine.